# Ignite - explain about 31100 time server port

Tags: time, port, ignite

Can anyone please explain, why the ignite is using the 31100 port. I have got the info in web as it is a time server port. I couldn't get anything other than this info.

Answer (score 1):

I see following configuration options in Ignite project:

```
/** Base port number for time server. */
private int timeSrvPortBase = DFLT_TIME_SERVER_PORT_BASE; // 31100

/** Port number range for time server. */
private int timeSrvPortRange = DFLT_TIME_SERVER_PORT_RANGE; // 100


/**
 * Gets base UPD port number for grid time server. Time server will be started on one of free ports in range
 * {@code [timeServerPortBase, timeServerPortBase + timeServerPortRange - 1]}.
 * <p>
 * Time server provides clock synchronization between nodes.
 *
 * @return Time
 */
public int getTimeServerPortBase() {
    return timeSrvPortBase;
}


/**
 * Defines port range to try for time server start.
 *
 * If port range value is <tt>0</tt>, then implementation will try bind only to the port provided by
 * {@link #setTimeServerPortBase(int)} method and fail if binding to this port did not succeed.
 *
 * @return Number of ports to try before server initialization fails.
 */
public int getTimeServerPortRange() {
    return timeSrvPortRange;
}
```

But I don't see any usage of this methods in other places. Looks like and obsolete feature. I've just started one server node of 2.10 and didn't see any open ports in range 311xx (sudo netstat -atnp | grep 311[0-9][0-9] was empty). Are you sure that your Ignite instance exposes this port? What version do you use?